# discord py how to create function

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

how to create a function that gives a role and calls it.
I need a function that give a role and how to call it

I try to

```
async def test():
    await bot.get_channel(870197219192614943).send('test')
```

and

```
asyncio.run(test())
```

but it's no working

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) to learn how to use discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use this:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await bot.get_channel(870197219192614943).send('Hello, World!')
```

Now if you send a test message with the bot prefix at the beginning to the guild chat, where there is a bot message, you will receive a response to the channel with this id

Comment: I don't need command, I need asyncio fiction that makes await method. And how to run this function

Answer (score -1):

Just name the function differently if I understand you correctly

```py
async def name_():
    pass

async def name():
    pass
```

Comment: Ok, how to run it?